# How to fix "Unable to find a specification" for lib that fork from github

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift5

I fork `material` from https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios
and this is my fork https://github.com/goodboygb1/material-components-ios

then i try to install this fork using CocoaPods but i've got this error `[!] Unable to find a specification for 'Material'.`

this is my podfile

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

workspace 'CalCal'

def mainPods
  pod 'OneSignal', '~> 2.10.1'
end


def corePods
  pod 'AlamofireNetworkActivityLogger', '~> 2.4'
  pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 5.2.0'
  pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'
  pod 'SwipeView'
  pod 'Material', :git => 'https://github.com/goodboygb1/material-components-ios.git'
```

this is head part of my MaterialComponents.podspec

```
load 'scripts/generated/icons.rb'

Pod::Spec.new do |mdc|
  mdc.name         = "MaterialComponents"
  mdc.version      = "124.2.0"
  mdc.authors      = "The Material Components authors."
  mdc.summary      = "A collection of stand-alone production-ready UI libraries focused on design details."
  mdc.homepage     = "https://github.com/goodboygb1/material-components-ios"
  mdc.license      = "Apache 2.0"
  mdc.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/goodboygb1/material-components-ios.git",
                       :tag => "v#{mdc.version}" }
  mdc.platform     = :ios
  mdc.requires_arc = true
  mdc.ios.deployment_target = '11.0'
```

How can i fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Can use pod file for MaterialComponents. Check below image.
[image]

Comment: i've to use MaterialComponents instead of Material right?